# Scilab double integral

Tags: scilab

Below is the code for my program. I'm attempting to find the value of the integral of 1/ln(x), and then evaluate the integral from 0 to x, with this as the integrand. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, but I am quite new to Scilab.

```
t = input("t");
x=10; while x<t, x=x+10,
function y=f(x), y=(1/(log (x))), endfunction
I=intg(2,x,f);
function z=g(x), z=I, endfunction
W = intg(0,x,z);
W
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure on what you are trying to achieve, but I reformatted your code and added some suggestions to documentation.
Maybe it will help you in finding the answer.

### While loop

You can convert your [while loop](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.1/en_US/while.html) to a [for loop](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.1/en_US/for.html)

**Your code**

```
x=10; 
while x<t
   x=x+10
   //some code
end
```

**Could be**

```
for x=10:10:t
   //some code
end
```

### Functions

In your code, you redeclare the two functions every single iteration of the while loop. You could declare them outside the while loop and call them inside the loop.

### Reformatted

```
t = input("Please provide t: ");

// The function of 1/ln(x)
function y=f(x), y=1/log(x), endfunction

// Every time g(x) is called the current value of I is returned
function z=g(x), z=I, endfunction

for x=10:10:t

    //Find definite integral of function f from 2 to x 
    I = intg(2,x,f);

    //Find definite integral of I from 0 to x
    W = intg(0,x,g);

    disp( string(W) ); 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I know the question is porbably outdated; but the topic is still active. And I was looking for a code with double integral.
Here, it looks strange to use "intg" just to calculate the area of the rectangle defined by its diagonal ((0,0), (x,I)): the result is just x*I...
May be the initial aim was to consider "I" as a function of "x" (but in this case there is a convergence problem at x=1...); so restricting the integration of "I" to something above 1 gives the following code:

`x=10:10:100;W2=integrate('integrate(''1/log(x2)'',''x2'',2,x1)','x1',1.001,x);`

Note the use of integration variables x1 and x2, plus the use of quotes...